# Invalid UICollectionView Update

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a sectioned `uicollectionview` with nested cells that can be deleted on tap.

My goal is to display cells from the datasource if available, and if not, to show a "placeholder" cell stating no data is currently available.

My issue emerges on delete of a last remaining cell under a given section. My `numberOfItemsInSection` is 1 specifically for the "placeholder" cell but should be 0 to align to the datasource of 0 where no more data is available.

Any thoughts on workarounds?

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if sectionItems[section].count == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    else {
        return sectionItems[section].count
    }
}

func onTap() {
    self.sectionItems[indexPath.section]?.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    self.exampleCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete your last item, you need to instead reload for the "No Items" cell. Something like this should work:

```
func onTap() {
    sectionItems[indexPath.section]?.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    let isEmpty = sectionItems[indexPath.section]?.count ?? 0 == 0

    exampleCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        if isEmpty {
            self.exampleCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        } else {
            self.exampleCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }, completion: nil})
}
```

Essentially you need to tell the collectionView that there will still be one cell there after the update when the last item is removed.